# Using external chaincodes on multiple peers of the same Org?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I am using Fabric 2.0 and external chaincode feature. I have an organization with 2 endorsing peers. I tested external chaincodes with one peer and it works, but how to use it with multiple peers?

Fabric docs says: **"Instead of building and launching the chaincode on every peer, chaincode can now run as a service whose lifecycle is managed outside of Fabric"**. Does it mean that I need only one external chaincode container regardless of the number of peers?

Do I need to install chaincode on a second peer too? Also during the chaincode installation it gives me CCID which I use inside the chaincode. But if I install the chaincode on a second peer it gives me another CCID and I don’t know what to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging in to the HLF chaincode documentation and many practical experiments, I found the answers to my questions.

> Does it mean that I need only one external chaincode container regardless of the number of peers?

You can use one external container for **the same** chaincode packages (with identical CCIDs).

> Do I need to install chaincode on a second peer too?

Yes, you need to install chaincode package on all endorsing peers of the organization.

> If I install the chaincode on a second peer it gives me another CCID and I don’t know what to do with it.

If you want to use the same external chaincode container for the several organization peers, you must install the same chaincode package on these peers, instead of creating new package for each peer (this was my fail, I created new package for the second peer and it generated different CCID).

Comment: How can we ensure the chaincode installed second peer having the same package-id?
I see even if the chaincode package is the same, the later try to install chaincode to a peer will have different package-id.

Comment: you can query installed chaincodes using `peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled` command. It gives you installed chaincodes with a package ids. [Here is the docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/peerlifecycle.html#peer-lifecycle-chaincode-queryinstalled).

Answer (score 1):

External builders give you the flexibility to determine how/where/when your chaincode is actually built.  You could for instance:

- Build your chaincode as a docker container, push it to a docker repository, and simply pull the image during the 'external builder' process.
- Have each peer build a copy of a chaincode binary locally using a toolchain in the local filesystem.
- Build a binary and push it out as part of the install package, and simply execute it.

Regardless of where/how/when your chaincode is actually built, you will need to install a chaincode package on every peer which will execute it.  You will also need to have your peers configured with the correct external builder to consume your package type.